# how to get quarter, half year, yearly and 24 months reports in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, report

I am working on requirement of generating reports for every 1, 3, 6, 12, and 24 months respectively where user selects his choice by a select dropdown. First I wrote query to generate report for 1 month which was worked fine. But I am not sure how to make that selection dynamic based on user selection.

My query is below:

```
switch($months){
    case "1":
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT count(*) as totalrows FROM today_analysis WHERE order_status=:order_status AND MONTH(track_date)=MONTH(CURDATE())");
        break;
    case "3":
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT count(*) as totalrows FROM today_analysis WHERE order_status=:order_status AND CEIL(MONTH(track_date) / 3)");
        break;
    case "6":
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT count(*) as totalrows FROM today_analysis WHERE order_status=:order_status AND CEIL(MONTH(track_date) / 6)");
        break;
    case "12":
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT count(*) as totalrows FROM today_analysis WHERE order_status=:order_status AND CEIL(MONTH(track_date) / 12)");
        break;
    case "24":
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT count(*) as totalrows FROM today_analysis WHERE order_status=:order_status AND CEIL(MONTH(track_date) / 24)");
        break;
}
```

My Select dropdown is:

```
<select name="month_analysis" id="month_analysis" class="month_analysis">
            <option value="1" <?php echo (isset($_GET['monthly']) && $_GET['monthly']=='1')?'selected':''?>>Current Month</option>
            <option value="3" <?php echo (isset($_GET['monthly']) && $_GET['monthly']=='3')?'selected':''?> >3 Months</option>
            <option value="6" <?php echo (isset($_GET['monthly']) && $_GET['monthly']=='6')?'selected':''?> >6 Months</option>
            <option value="12" <?php echo (isset($_GET['monthly']) && $_GET['monthly']=='12')?'selected':''?> >12 Months</option>
            <option value="24" <?php echo (isset($_GET['monthly']) && $_GET['monthly']=='24')?'selected':''?> >24 Months</option>
</select>
```

Presently, The query seems to be working but I am not sure if it is working fine or not. Please any suggestions/help? Thanks.

Comment: You probably want to use `BETWEEN`, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mysql's [date_sub() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) to calculate which records fall into the required date range:

```
SELECT count(*) as totalrows FROM today_analysis WHERE order_status=:order_status AND track_date>=date_sub(curdate(),interval 1 month)
```

Based on the value in your dropdown menu, you can dynamically assign the number of months in the date_sub() function in the place of the value `1`:

```
SELECT count(*) as totalrows FROM today_analysis WHERE order_status=:order_status AND track_date>=date_sub(curdate(),interval :monthes month)
```

Comment: But I want to skip the current month that means if it is 3 months then last 3 months excluding current month.

Comment: Then you have to use the `between ... and ...` operator.

Comment: Ok but Could you please tell me how to do that?